# Can not get the function returning value using PHP

Tags: php, query-string

I need one help.I am unable to get the value which function is returning using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
  function encrypt($id){
    $key=md5('onlinepharmacy', true);
    $id = base_convert($id, 10, 36); // Save some space
    $data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $id, 'ecb');
    $data = bin2hex($data);
    return $data;
}

?>

<a href="health.php?h_i=<?php encrypt(12) ?>" class="detall">Go for Details</a>
```

from the above code i am not getting `h_i value`.it is coming as blank.I need to set query string value(`h_i=`) but unable to fetch.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Just print it: `<?php echo encrypt(12) ?>`

Comment: You may be able to simplify that to `<?= encrypt(12) ?>` which is more compact and easier to read.

Comment: i would say echo is easier to read myself

Answer (score 1):

When you are returning value from function, you need to use echo() to display it.
  // in your case

and if you dont want to use echo in html, than you have to echo() value from function rather than returning it.

```
function encrypt($id){
    $key=md5('onlinepharmacy', true);
    $id = base_convert($id, 10, 36); // Save some space
    $data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $id, 'ecb');
    $data = bin2hex($data);`enter code here`
    echo $data;
}
<a href="health.php?h_i=<?php encrypt(12) ?>" class="detall">Go for Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The end statement syntax is missing and you should assign the returned value to a variable incase you want you use it again. Good practice to make update and extension easy.

see a working code below;

```
function encrypt($id){
    $key=md5('onlinepharmacy', true);
    $id = base_convert($id, 10, 36); // Save some space
    $data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $id, 'ecb');
    $data = bin2hex($data);`enter code here`
    return $data;
}
<a href="health.php?h_i=<?php echo encrypt(12); ?>" class="detall">Go for Details</a>
```